# How to specify a type in Typescript which represents the union of 2 functions

Tags: typescript, type-definition

Let's suppose that I have 2 function

```
export const functionA = () => {// do stuff}
export const functionB = () => {// do stuff}
```

and I want to create another function that accepts as input only either `functionA` or `functionB`, for instance

```
export const anotherFunction = functionAorB => {// do stuff }
```

Is there a way in Typescript to specify a type representing only either `functionA` or `functionB`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using defined functions as parameters in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600170/using-defined-functions-as-parameters-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a type on a specific function.  `functionA` is a value not a type.  However, you can do:

```
type FuncA = (x: number) => number;
type FuncB = (x: string) => string;
type FuncEither = FuncA | FuncB;
```

Functions combine in slightly unintuitive ways.  `FuncEither` will be `(x: number & string): number | string`